# Simulating Network Latency with .NET Framework

Tags: .net, bandwidth, latency, low-latency

Does microsoft offer any means of simulating latency on .net? They do have it for XNA, but I cannot find it for .net framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975762.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I simply hook up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and run all of my IP traffic through it.  There is an option in under Rules -> Performance to **Simulate Modem Speeds**.  You can actually adjust this in the config file for Fiddler should you wish to make it even slower than 56kbps.

Comment: +1 A proxy that can shape traffic throughput is a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simulate latency when and where you need it? If you have enough control over the code you're using you could insert a call to

`Threading.Thread.Sleep()`

to simulate latency if it works with what you're doing. I've used it before to manually insert latency to test out a parallel email dispatching class (dispatches by batches). It might work for your code as well.

Comment: Then use a proxy that simulates latency! This is another way to simulate latency! You can't make your network latent! You will have to simulate it somehow!